# Java: Creating a file from a non-hierarchical URI which points to a directory in a jar

Tags: java, jar, uri

I am using reflection to find all the directories in a certain package, and then returning those directories as java.io.Files so that I can extract class files from them. My method for getting all the directories in a package is this:

```
private static List<File> findDirs(String packageName) throws IOException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    assert classLoader != null;

    String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
    Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL resource = resources.nextElement();
        URI uri = resource.toURI();
        File f = new File(uri);// this line throws the exception
        result.add(f);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works perfectly fine when running my application from the source code. However, Once I deploy it,and run it, the method findDirs fails, as the File constructor throws an IllegalArgumentsException"URI is not Hierarchical".

I have debuged the code, and the URI in question which is causing the problem is:
`jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-activemq-5.5.1/bin/../lib/App.jar!/com/demo/payload`

Whereas I have no problem with the URI when running from source:
`file:/C:/Marcus/JavaProjects/App/build/prod/classes/com/demo/payload`

How can I create a file pointing to the payload directory within the App.jar from a non-herarchical URI such as the one mentioned?

I can get as far as creating a JarFile that points to the App.jar itself using `JarURLConnection`, and can then get a JarEntry pointing to the directory I'm searching for, but can't seem to convert this entry to a file...

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong to expect you'll be able to treat all stuff you get from `#getResources(String)` are valid `File` references. In your run case, it's a reference of a file within your application/library's Jar. You should access these `URL`s as such: get `InputStream`s (`URL#openStream`) on them to read the contents instead of trying to hop through `File`.

In order to get `File`s, you'll need to figure out when you're looking at an in-jar URL, then possibly extract the file from the ZIP (because JARs are ZIPs) in order to get a proper, first-class citizen `File`.

Comment: -1, as it does not answer the question at all (even though the facts stated are valid)

Comment: Agreed, but unfortunately I am working with other peoples code here, and to avoid having to rewrite the entire class I need the findDirs method to return a File pointing to a directory, whether the directory is in a Jar or on the fileSystem, Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @stryba Added notes about getting stuff from Zip. However, it's not something I would recommend doing in a production setup - it's dangerous, classloaders could reference remote data.

Comment: @Romain: agreed not a recommendable solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.zip.ZipFile` whenever you point to the inside of a jar file. Just load the referenced jar file in a `ZipFile` and use `getEntry` or `entries` of it to retrieve elements within the jar.

Comment: As I said at the end of the question I am able to get access to the underlying Zipentry that corresponds to the directory I'm trying to create a file for, but then how can I actually Create a java.io.File instance from this entry?

Comment: The question is whether you need a `List<File>` rather then something like `List<URL>` or `List<URI>` for that matter. With `File` you won't solve this problem.